# How to organize priorities div?

Tags: css-float, html

I have 3 objects:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
    <div class="center">Center</div>     
</div>
```

Define CSS overview following:

```html
<style>
    body{width: 100%;padding: 0; margin: 0;}  
    .container{width:960px; margin:30px auto;}
    .left{width:25%; height:100px; background:#f60;;}
    .right{width:25%; height:100px; background:#ff0;;}
    .center{width:50%; height:100px;  background:#f0f;;}
</style>
```

The requirement is that I have sorted the `div` according to the following priority:

1/Left - Right - Center

```css
.left{float:left;}
.right{float:left;}
.center{float:left;}
```

2/Left - Center- Right

```css
.left{float:left;}
.right{float:right;}
.center{float:left;}
```

3/Center- Right - Left

```css
.left{float:right;}
.right{float:right;}
.center{float:left;}
```

4/Right - Center - Left

```css
.left{float:right;}
.right{float:left;}
.center{float:right;}
```

5/Right - Left - Center ???

6/Center- Left - Right ???

Required (5) and (6) I can't do.
If I use `position:absolute` can do this, but "container" not automatically resize height when I change the width of the browser (I use responsive theme - divide `div` by the percentage)

Anyone have CSS solution without changing anything in the HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `position: absolute;` with `left` according to the width of the other Div in the position you want. And `position: relative;` to container.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the "position: absolute" seems is not suitable for me in this case, because "container" not automatically resize height when I change the width of the browser (i use responsive theme - 960 Grid Layout). I have modified the question to suit my task. Best regards